# Nested numerical integration strategies

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics

I have the following space time integral

```
fint[zr_, Ω_, τ_, c_, E0_, ϕk_, θk_, 
  kγ_] := 
 E0^3 NIntegrate[
   E^(-I c kγ t + I kγ z Cos[θk] + 
     I kγ r Cos[ϕ - ϕk] Sin[θk])
     E^(-( ((t + z/c)^2)/τ^2) - (2 (t - z/c)^2)/τ^2)
     E^(-((3 r^2 zr Ω)/(2 c (z^2 + zr^2))))
     zr^3/(z^2 + zr^2)^(3/2)
     Cos[(z/c - t) Ω + (r^2 z Ω)/(
      2 c (z^2 + zr^2)) - 
      ArcTan[z/zr]] Cos[(z/c - t) Ω + (
      r^2 z Ω)/(2 c (z^2 + zr^2)) - 
      ArcTan[z/zr]] Cos[(-z/c - t) Ω - (
      r^2 z Ω)/(2 c (z^2 + zr^2)) + ArcTan[z/zr]] r, {r,
     0, Infinity}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {z, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 14, 
   Method ->  {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

The integrals over $t$ and $\phi$ can be done analytically but I would like to keep it as it is because the real function I am trying to integrate has more complicated angular and time dependencies. After trial and error I found setting Method ->  {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0} helps the evaluation. I have evaluated this for several values of $\phi_k$ and I know the result is independent of $\phi_k$. The results are given below for $\phi_k=\pi/3, \,\pi/4$

```
In[79]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 fint[1/100, 10^(-2), 1, 1, 1/10, π/3, π/7, 2]]

During evaluation of In[79]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[79]:= NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.02435272394469060212206806417003520587868324711867019482319269710+7.515966867726958380713095081317123450063093820659723312314352281*10^-6 I and 0.01004183362042224153701499949281249977449042420790808802936609201`64. for the integral and error estimates.

Out[79]= {72.853, 0.000024352723944691 + 7.515966868*10^-9 I}


In[80]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 fint[1/100, 10^(-2), 1, 1, 1/10, π/4, π/7, 2]]

During evaluation of In[80]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[80]:= NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.02429621239712290711277080253441765553764931778311090416124120875+0.00001376034310890542628748050635168806150242897727593306633452173450 I and 0.01079603116856488564296055157476262207724238912513306631140535502`64. for the integral and error estimates.

Out[80]= {77.6721, 0.000024296212397123 + 1.3760343109*10^-8 I}
```

The result I am expecting to be is 0.0000243204 so the numerical error starts on the third non-trivial digit. I have two questions

1. It takes almost 80 seconds to evaluate. Is there a way to bring this time down ?
2. How can I improve accuracy ?

Comment: I thank @MarcoB  for the edit making it more readable.